# how to replace Windows.Beep with modern beep sound

Tags: delphi

how to replace Windows.Beep with modern beep sound  that comes from speakers with adjustable volume?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this one

```
uses MMSystem;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  sndPlaySound('C:\Windows\Media\sound.wav',
    SND_NODEFAULT Or SND_ASYNC Or SND_LOOP);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  sndPlaySound(nil, 0); // Stops the sound
end;
```

Comment: I like this one

        sndPlaySound('ding.wav',SND_ASYNC );

Comment: Be sure to write your own function "AppBeep", don't scatter
calls to sndPlaySound( hardcodedFilenameHere) throughout your app!

Answer (score 10):

Funny you should ask. I was just reading about the history of the windows beep. The Americans with Disabilities act has forced the Beep API to not change for the last 20 something years.

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20151017145119/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/larryosterman/archive/2010/01/04/what-s-up-with-the-beep-driver-in-windows-7.aspx)

> For Windows 7, we resolved the issue
> completely – we moved all the
> functionality that used to be
> contained in Beep.Sys into the user
> mode system sounds agent – now when
> you call the Beep() API instead of
> manipulating the 8254 chip the call is
> re-routed into a user mode agent which
> actually plays the sounds.

So the short answer is: Get Windows 7.
A longer answer would be: Don't use the beep api. Get a beep noise and play it like you'd play any other noise.

Comment: Don't you think an OS upgrade is overkill for wanting to change the Beep?

Comment: Well, @Ken, if you want to call `Beep` specifically *and* you want a different sound, then a newer OS is your only option, and thus not overkill.

Comment: Um... @Rob, if you're so intent on using Beep() specifically that you'd rather change your OS than change your code to use something else, I'd suspect you have a screw loose somewhere. ;-)

Comment: Well the question was basically, "I want Beep() to be different." Which is weird. I want a lot of the  windows API to be different. Theres not really much I can do about it. But if someone really has to use Beep() for some reason and wants it to play through the regular sound hardware then so far nobody here has come up with a different solution.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to use the "standard" beeps used by Windows when a MessageBox is displayed, you can call `Windows.MessageBeep(MessageID)` where *MessageID* maps to the same values as the icon ids for MessageBox (MB_OK, MB_ERROR etc).

One problem with this is that users can map any, or no sound to particular ids.

Comment: People turning off sounds is not a problem! It certainly shouldn't be.  Your user interface should not rely on sounds. There are people out there that do not hear sounds, even when Windows is still configured to make them...

Comment: @Marjan Indeed it shouldn't be - it should be completely up to the computer user. Using MessageBeep makes the program work more like Windows itself, which is generally a good thing

Answer (score 0):

You can replace beep calls with executing ET BEEP which has an editor for all sorts of alien sounds.

https://www.encodeteam.com/beep.htm